# How do I go directly to a particular (short) option on a manpage

Tags: shell, manpage

Often I will open up the manpage for a command already knowing the option I am searching for and read its description. Sometimes simply searching for the option works immediately, sometimes the option is referenced elsewhere, sometimes the option just appears as a substring in the preceding text.

As a concrete example, on *my* computer, right now, this is the sequence of commands to get to the `-l` option of `ls`:

```
man ls
/-l
nnnnnnn
```

In this particular case there is only one group of options and they are alphabetically sorted, so I could just scroll down and find the option, or do as above. In other cases not so much. Regardless, I would like to go directly to the line.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and so is off-topic for SO, but `man` itself just sends its output to your default pager; I don't believe any of them are smart enough to detect what's an option in a manpage and jump to it.

Comment: @Wooble Is looking at documentation not related to programming?

Comment: The documentation to a unix tool you're not hacking on yourself? Not really.

Comment: @Wooble This actually came up a lot when I was hacking on gnugo, but usually comes up now when I'm working with git or bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pager is `less`, which it often is, it supports regular expression search. For your example this works:

```
man ls
/^ *-l\b
```

Which anchors the match to lines starting with arbitrary whitespace followed by `-l` and a word-boundary `\b`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know I could do regexen while searching!

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I can do a search:

```
/     -l
```

Or even just

```
/ -l
```

This doesn't always work immediately, though, so I'm hoping there's a better answer still.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a "find next" command for search? I've never been able to find one, which means that if a string shows up multiple times I have to retype the query repeatedly to move to the next result.

Comment: @octern: If your pager is `less`, use `n` for next and `N` for previous.